# What is the difference between 'test' and 'test.sh' while running shell scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have added a `./bin/` folder in my home directory.

And I placed two files in the `./bin` folder, one with just a filename and the other one is a filename.ext.

File names are `test` and `test.sh`:

[image: screen-shot-1]

When I run with just filename, the terminal doesn't showing any output, but when I tried with the test.sh, the script gets executing:

[image: screen-shot-2]

My Question is, can I run the script just by using the filename such as "test" on the terminal, instead of giving the "test.sh".

Comment: `test` is already used by a different application, and that is what you are running. See `man test`

Comment: Please don't post images of text, just copy the text and use the formatting tools.

Comment: Specifically, `test` is the name of a bash shell builtin - which will be executed first regardless of where `~/bin` occurs in your `PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How shell executes commands:

From bash manual:

> If  the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, bash searches each element of the PATH for  a  directory containing  an executable file by that name.

This means that functions and shell built-in commands take precedence first, and if there's none - it searches for the command in the list of directories that are specified in `PATH` variable.

## Why  my 'test' command didn't work ?

What you encountered is `test` command which is a [built-in command compatible with original Bourne shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) in `bash`. This command is silent, and is used for simple logic, arithmetic evaluation, and string evaluation.  It is used in logic and if statements:

```
bash-4.3$ test 1 -le 2 && echo "1 is less that or equal to 2"
1 is less that or equal to 2
bash-4.3$ if test 1 -le 2 ; then echo "1 is less than or equal to 2"; fi
1 is less than or equal to 2
```

Note that `test` and `[` exactly the same:

```
bash-4.3$ [ 1 -le 2 ] && echo "1 is less that or equal to 2"
1 is less that or equal to 2
bash-4.3$ if [ 1 -le 2 ] ; then echo "1 is less than or equal to 2"; fi
1 is less than or equal to 2
```

There's also `/usr/bin/test` which is among the standard utilities, and exist for portability and compatibility. If there was no `test` built-in in your shell, it would look through the `PATH` variable, and if `/usr/bin/` happened to be before your `~/bin` on the list - it would run `/usr/bin/test`. Here's an example of that:

```
bash-4.3$ enable -n test
bash-4.3$ PATH="$HOME/bin/:$PATH" test
I am ~/bin/test
```

Using `enable -n` command we turn off the built-in `test`, and run `test` temporarily with modified `PATH` such  my `~/bin` is first on the list. The shell looks at the list, and finds my shell script `~/bin/test` and ran it.

**NOTE:** *please don't do this! The above example is for demonstration only ! This is not a good way to run your scripts and is not recommended. Use appropriate naming, never name your commands same as shell built-ins or existing utilities. You have been warned.*

## Why did test.sh work ?

What happened in your `test.sh` case is that there's no built-in or functions  called `test.sh` and therefore shell searched every directory in `PATH` list, until it found your `test.sh` file and ran it. That's why it works.

## Does this behavior relate to file extensions ?

No. This has nothing to do with file extensions and in fact for most files extension is irrelevant. Shell cares for location of what you type in command-prompt, if it's a built-in or function or alias,  and if the file you mention has executable permissions set.

Additionally, it cares about appropriate `#!` line (which is more formally known as [interpreter directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_directive)), because if you have shell script written say for C-shell but it doesn't have appropriate `#!` line at the top, and you try to run it with `bash` - the shell will try to run it but it will break due to incompatible syntax.

More generally, Linux and Unix-like systems mostly care about [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) which are first several bytes in a file that identify the file type.